# Reverse multiple data plotting

Tags: excel, vba, plot, reverse

I have 3 data sets, captured with time stamp. I want to plot the data sets based on time stamp, following the passage of time. Pls refer to the attached picture.

plots(1): simply inserted the chart using the data (A1: D16), with the primary axis for y1 and y2, and the secondary axis for y3, and all the plots are contrary to the passage of time.. I want to change the plots following the passage of time (that is, older data to the left and newer data to the right), so that all plots are shown following the passage of time (monotone increasing)..

plots(2): so, I checked the check box "categories in reverse order" in the Format Axis settings. But this reverses x axis and the plots for y1 and y2 using the primary axis (GOOD), not the one for y3 using the secondary axis (BAD), so I have two plots following  the passage of time, and one reversing the passage of time.,

Could someone let me know how to solve it to have all plots which are monotone increasing? Any solutions with/without VBA would be OK. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: IIUC, why not just change the Format Axis settings on the secondary axis to be "categories in reverse order" as well?

Answer (score 0):

Each axis has it's own 'format axis' option.  left click the axis (right or left), right-click>>format axis.  Choose the  axis options >> values in reverse order.

Comment: When I tried following your suggestion, it simply changes y3 axis upside down, so the y3 plot moved symmetrically with respect to horizontal line, not to vertical line. So the problem remains..